# Support ProgressDialog in a Static Context

Tags: android, android-activity, android-support-library

I can do this:

```
 ((Activity) mContext).setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

But not this:

```
 ((Activity) mContext).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

`It says this method is undefined for the type Activity`

Can anyone tell me how to properly use the support version of this?

Comment: I'm not sure but have you tried using your "Activity name"( where you are calling this) instead of using `Activity`?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri  that worked!  I had tried `SherlockActivity` and `SherlockFragmentActivity` and `FragmentActivity` and none of those did it.  But the actual Activity name did.  Go ahead and set as answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For casting the `Context` object, use your "Activity name"(where you are calling this function) instead of using `Activity`. Supposing your activity name is `MyAcivity`, do something like:

```
((MyActivity) mContext).setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```